# append iframe by clicking youtube screenshot of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I have a long list of videos and there are a lot of iframes that slows all of the browsers. I decided to use their screenshots only. By clicking on the screenshot, the iframe will be shown and screeshot will be hidden. I just set the iframe to be hidden by default, but I want the iframes to be appended dynamically so that iframes would not be written in HTML code at all, here is my code:

```
<div class="youtube">
                <div class="description">Desciption 1</div>
                <div class="youtube_thumb">
                    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/mqf6K6qYOWg/0.jpg" style="width:325px;border:0;" />
                    <iframe width="325" height="250" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/mqf6K6qYOWg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="youtube">
                <div class="description">Desciption 2</div>
                <div class="youtube_thumb">
                    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/GIc14HyiLNs/0.jpg" style="width:325px;border:0;" />
                    <iframe width="325" height="250" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/GIc14HyiLNs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and so on..

and javascript:

```
$('.youtube_thumb > img').click(function(){
            var $img = $(this);
            $img.hide();
            $img.next().show();
        });
```

and style:

```
.youtube_thumb iframe { display:none; }
.youtube_thumb:hover { cursor:pointer; }
```

As you can see and probably know, the screenshot I get is directly from youtube, thus the screenshot link: `mqf6K6qYOWg/0.jpg` and in frame link: `/embed/mqf6K6qYOWg` are the same, I think it is possible by using the link of the screenshot, to append the iframe with the same link. How i can do this?

Comment: `$("<iframe src='foo' ... ></iframe>").insertAfter(this);`

Comment: @epascarello i didnt answer it ) i want to be iframe appended, not hidden

Comment: OH I misread that. WHOOPS. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.youtube_thumb > img').click(function(){
    var parts = this.src.split("/");  //grab the url and split it into parts
    var id = parts[parts.length-2]; //grab the second to last piece
    $('<iframe width="325" height="250" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + id + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>').insertAfter(this);  //append the iframe
    $(this).hide();  // .remove();
});
```

Comment: as i understand i have to insert it in: `$('.youtube_thumb > img').click(function(){ HERE });` ?

Comment: sorry ) forgot to remove style )) my bad

Comment: you could also change the binding to $('.youtube_thumb > img').one('click', function(){ to trash the binding after the click

Answer (score 1):

wrap the img into an a tag with

`<a class="wrap" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/mqf6K6qYOWg"><img /></a>`

jquery

```
$('.wrap').on('click', function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).before('<iframe width="325" height="250" src="'+src+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
    $(this).remove();
    return false;
)}
```

Comment: thank you! but i have a long list of videos and links, so it will be a little bit hard to change and wrap all the links... can u change it without wrapping the links?

Comment: Good method but `"http://img.youtube.com/vi/mqf6K6qYOWg/0.jpg" .replace('/0.jpg', '')` != `http://www.youtube.com/embed/mqf6K6qYOWg`

Comment: yes this method doesnt work... btw i removed all the frames there